# use of InjectionToken for multiple provider in angular 4

Tags: angular

```
import {TestService1} from '../../../../test1.service';
import {TestService2} from '../../../../test2.service';
import {AbstractclassService} from '../../../../abstractclass.service';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

const SERVICE1_or_SERVICE2 = new InjectionToken<string>('AbstractclassService');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-gauge',
  templateUrl: './gauge.component.html',
  providers: [
  {
  provide: SERVICE1_or_SERVICE2,
  useValue: Service1,
  multi: true
},

{
  provide: SERVICE1_or_SERVICE2,
  useValue: Service2,
  multi: true
}

  ],
  styleUrls: ['./gauge.component.css']
})
```

I want to use an abstract class in which i injected TestService1 and TestService2 to show some data in my component. How could i use the INjectionToken right to decide every time which Service i want to use?

Comment: There is no way to do that. If you inject `SERVICE1_or_SERVICE2` you'll get both in an array and can pick which one you want.

Comment: What would be the criteria which one you actually want to have injected?

Comment: Service1 or Service2 get some data and i want that the Service who get the data inject them in my AbstractclassService (SERVICE1_or_SERVICE2). And this is actually happening, but in my component i didnt find a way to show the data from my abstract class, because the abstractclass get the data from different Services